# Using classes instead of anonymous type in join C# WPF Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, join, datagridview

I need to change from using an **anonymous** type in my JOIN statement to using **classes** instead. My coding:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
{
   var Join = (from a in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
               join b in DC.tblProjects
               on a.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
               join c in DC.tblClientLoginDetails
               on b.ProjectID equals c.ClientLoginID
               where c.ClientLoginID != null
               select new
               { 
                  b.ProjectID, 
                  b.ProjectName, 
                  b.ProjectStatus, 
                  a.EmployeeName, 
                  a.EmployeeSurname,
                  c.ClientName,
                }).ToList();

    dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = Join;
}
```

My classes: **PIDData** & **EIDData**

**PIDData**:

```
public struct PDData
{
    public string _project;

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

**EIDData**:

```
    public string _sts;

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public Binary SetImage { get; set; }
}
```

Now I am very new to c# and coding in general, so this gets a little tricky and frustrating for me. I do not know how to use my classes instead of the anonymous type in my join statement.

Using the classes will help me to more easily manage my data from a datagrid in my program. Please share any advice or let me know if there is any more information that I can give to help in answering the question, thank you!

**EDIT:**

Here is what the JOIN is looking like right now:

```
        using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
           List<Match> Join = (from a in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                        join b in DC.tblProjects
                        on a.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
                        join c in DC.tblClientLoginDetails
                        on b.ProjectID equals c.ClientLoginID
                        where c.ClientLoginID != null
                        select new Match
                        { 
                            ProjectIDM = b.ProjectID, 
                            ProjectNameM = b.ProjectName, 
                            ProjectStatusM = b.ProjectStatus, 

                            EmployeeNameM = a.EmployeeName, 
                            EmployeeSurnameM = a.EmployeeSurname,

                            ClientNameM = c.ClientName,
                        }).ToList();

           dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = Join;
        }
```

Nautious, I also created the class that you suggested.

I am not getting any errors...which is very good, but there isn't data displaying in my datagridview anymore. I think it might be because of this:

> dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = Join;

Comment: Woups. My Bad.. The Fields in the Match Class needs to be properties. See edit of answer

Comment: Thank you very much Nautious for your time and effort, that fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you make a class/struct that matches the data you wish to return:

```
public class Match
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public object ProjectStatus { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSurname { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
}
```

Then you create and fill instances in your `select new`:

```
select new Match
{
    ProjectID = b.ProjectID,
    ProjectName = b.ProjectName,
    ProjectStatus = b.ProjectStatus,

    EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName,
    EmployeeSurname = a.EmployeeSurname,

    ClientName = c.ClientName,
}).ToList();
```

now, your variable `Join` will be of type `List<Match>`

Comment: Thank you for you comment! Please view the EDIT on my question. :D I need to know how I can then bind the items to my datagrid, because there is no information displaying there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use  a struct witch is not a part of *DataClassesDataContext* you could use anonymous types, but then you can convert it to you own type

```
var Join = (from a in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
           join b in DC.tblProjects
           on a.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
           join c in DC.tblClientLoginDetails
           on b.ProjectID equals c.ClientLoginID
           where c.ClientLoginID != null
           select new
                    { 
                        ProjectID = b.ProjectID, 
                         ProjectName = b.ProjectName, 
                        ProjectStatus = b.ProjectStatus, 

                        EmployeeName = a.EmployeeName, 
                        EmployeeSurname = a.EmployeeSurname,

                        ClientName = c.ClientName,
                    }).ToList().Select(x => new PIDData
                   {
         ProjectID = b.ProjectID, 
         Name = b.ProjectName, 
          Status = b.ProjectStatus, 
                   }).ToList() ;
```